# how to find object in opencv and replace that with new pic in android?

Tags: android, image, opencv, replace

How can I find the red object in the image below with opencv in Android and fill it by my pattern like second pic ?

I need to create an app to fills the wall with a masking pattern automatically and, when the user clicks on a image pattern, then fills the picture with the selected pattern.

Please mentiona any library that does this.

Thank you for your help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**C++ Version, not suitable for direct use in Android**

I developed a solution for your problem; is not perfect but you can try it.
Please note that the red regions must be *really* red, so RGB(255,0,0).
In the image that you had provided the red regions weren't perfectly reds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

cv::Mat fillWall(cv::Mat homeImage, cv::Mat screenshot);

int main() 
{
  cv::Mat originalImage = cv::imread("original2.png");
  cv::Mat maskImage = cv::imread("maks.jpg");
  cv::Mat finalImage = fillWall(originalImage, maskImage);
  cv::imshow("result", finalImage);
  cv::waitKey(5000);
  return 0;
}

cv::Mat fillWall(cv::Mat originalImage, cv::Mat pattern) 
{
  cv::Mat output;
  cv::Mat rectHome;

  // Preproc
  cv::cvtColor(originalImage, originalImage, CV_RGBA2BGR);
  // Select only red regions in the originalImage.
  cv::inRange(originalImage, cv::Scalar(254, 0, 0), cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), rectHome);
  cv::Mat originalMask;
  rectHome.copyTo(originalMask);
  originalImage.copyTo(output);

  // Contours
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> allContours;
  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
  allContours.reserve(10);
  cv::findContours(rectHome, allContours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
  for (auto &c : allContours) {
    if (c.size() > 50) {
      contours.push_back(c);
    }
  }

  // Find the rotated rectangles for each contour
  // This approx the contours to rectangles.
  std::vector<cv::RotatedRect> minRect;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    minRect.push_back(cv::minAreaRect(cv::Mat(contours[i])));
  }

  for (int ci = 0; ci < minRect.size(); ci++) {
    cv::Point2f pointsRes[4], pointsIn[4];
    pointsIn[0] = cv::Point2f(10, 10) ;
    pointsIn[1] = cv::Point2f(pattern.cols - 10, 10);
    pointsIn[2] = cv::Point2f(pattern.cols - 10, pattern.rows - 10);
    pointsIn[3] = cv::Point2f(10, pattern.rows - 10);

    cv::Point2f rect[4];
    minRect[ci].points(rect);
    pointsRes[3] = rect[2];
    pointsRes[2] = rect[3];
    pointsRes[1] = rect[0];
    pointsRes[0] = rect[1];

    // Do a perspective transform in order to display
    // the pattern image with the correct orientation
    cv::Mat prsxTrnsf = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(pointsIn, pointsRes);
    cv::Mat outScreen;
    cv::warpPerspective(pattern, outScreen, prsxTrnsf, cv::  Size(originalImage.cols , originalImage.rows));
    cv::cvtColor(outScreen, outScreen, CV_BGRA2RGB);

    for (int row = 0; row < originalImage.rows; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < originalImage.cols; col++) {
        double inside = cv::pointPolygonTest(contours[ci],   cv::Point2f(col,row), false);
        if (originalMask.at<uchar>(row, col) == 255 && inside >= 0) {
          output.at<cv::Vec3b>(row, col) = outScreen.at<cv::Vec3b>(row, col);
        }
      }
    }
  }  
  cv::cvtColor(output, output, CV_BGR2RGBA);
  return output;
}
```

[image: Output image]

Note that the pattern image is random rotated; if you tell me how you want the pattern, I can adjust it. I think that this is a good place to start.

Comment: whats programming language used ? ndk ?or ...?please post here link of how to work like you on android. very very thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot that Android means Java. This is C++ code, you cannot use directly in an Android App. I think you two options here: try to translate the code using the OpenCV  for Java, or use directly the above C++ code following this link: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.2/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html

Comment: In any case, you can follow the algorithm proposed in the function *fillWall* and translate it for Android, should not be difficult.

Comment: Thanks but I need android version that very different in implementation.

Comment: Again, sorry, when I answered your question I forgot that Android means Java. I think that this answer could remain here for those who needs the C++ algorithm. Hope someone else can help you.